# List No of minutes worked by an employee using self join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server table **emp_swipe_rec** which has only 6 columns. I want to know how much time (in minutes) both employees A and B worked for today (last 24 hours). Employee A already swiped out for the day. Employee B is still working. We don't store two different columns for a swipe in/swipe out. We use swipe_type (I - In/ O- Out) to determine the employee is still working or swipe out.

I need the two outputs from the query.
Total Working Minutes of each Employee who swiped in last 24 hours. (Both swipe in/swipe out employees for the past 24 hours)
List of employees who are working right now along with their total minutes of work till they swipe in. (Only swipe in and not swipe out for past 24 hours)

| Employee_ID | Employee_Name | Swipe_Type | Swipe_In_Out_Time | Department | Emp_Swipe_Rec_PK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | I | 2021-03-07 08:00:00.000 | MARKETING | 1 |
| 2 | B | I | 2021-03-07 08:00:00.000 | SALES | 2 |
| 1 | A | O | 2021-03-07 15:00:00.000 | MARKETING | 3 |

I tried the below query but it says:

> invalid column name for starttime and endtime param inside the DATEDIFF row.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
SELECT one.EMPLOYEE_ID,one.EMPLOYEE_NAME
       one.SWIPE_IN_OUT_TIME AS starttime,
       two.SWIPE_IN_OUT_TIME AS endtime,
       DATEDIFF(minute,starttime,endtime) AS diff
FROM emp_swipe_rec one
INNER JOIN emp_swipe_rec two ON two.SWIPE_TYPE <> one.SWIPE_TYPE
WHERE one.Employee_Id = two.Employee_Id AND one.Department = two.Department
```

Comment: I tried the above query but it says invalid column name for starttime and endtime param inside the DATEDIFF row. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Kindly help.

Comment: You can't use an alias column name in a calculated column, use the actual column name. So `DATEDIFF(minute,starttime,endtime)` should be `DATEDIFF(minute,one.SWIPE_IN_OUT_TIME,two.SWIPE_IN_OUT_TIME)`

Comment: Your query does not limit the records to the last (full) 24 hours either..

Comment: You might need a more complex join condition than just a different ID, unless you can guarantee there are only 2 records for the period of interest.

Comment: @user15350142 please don't fundamentally change your question - your original question was about the error you received. By changing your question you invalidate the existing answers. This is not a debugging session. You ask a question, receive an answer. If you have another question ask a new question. I have rolled back your changes.

Comment: And when asking a question about obtaining the correct data (as opposed to a syntax issue), please ensure you provide enough sample data (ideally as DDL+DML) to demonstrate all end cases, and the most complex conditions that might arise. And then also show the expected results you wish to receive, the logic to describe how you obtain your results and your best attempt to accomplish that.

Comment: And why have you tagged both SQL Server 2008 + 2012? Please only tag the one of relevance.

Comment: Great question. It clarifies my question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this satisfies your first requirement "Total Working Minutes of each Employee who swiped in last 24 hours"

This returns one record for employee 1 as that is the only employee who has a sign out (in August 2021!?)

As this uses a window function, you will need to be using SQL Server 2012 or above, you have tagged both 2008 and 2012

```
;WITH SwipeIns AS
(
    SELECT  Employee_ID,
            Employee_Name,
            Swipe_In_Out_Time
    FROM    emp_swipe_rec 
    WHERE   Swipe_Type = 'I' AND
            Swipe_In_Out_Time > DATEADD(HOUR,-24,GETDATE()) AND
            Swipe_In_Out_Time < GETDATE()
),
SwipeOuts AS
(
    SELECT  Employee_ID,
            Swipe_In_Out_Time
    FROM    emp_swipe_rec 
    WHERE   Swipe_Type = 'O' AND
            Employee_ID IN (SELECT Employee_ID FROM SwipeIns) AND
            Swipe_In_Out_Time > DATEADD(HOUR,-24,GETDATE())
)

SELECT  Employee_ID,
        Employee_Name,
        SwipeIn,
        SwipeOut,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE,SwipeIn,SwipeOut) AS Duration
FROM    (
            SELECT  i.Employee_ID,
                    i.Employee_Name,
                    i.Swipe_In_Out_Time AS SwipeIn,
                    o.Swipe_In_Out_Time AS SwipeOut,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.Employee_ID ORDER BY o.Swipe_In_Out_Time) AS RowN
            FROM    SwipeIns i
                    JOIN SwipeOuts o
                        ON i.Employee_ID = o.Employee_ID
        ) a
WHERE   RowN = 1
```

Also, why is your table not normalized? Do you not have an employees table? EmployeeName and Department are redundant

Comment: Thanks much. I will try it out and i fixed the bad date issue on the description.

Comment: 1986 How do I get the list of currently swiped-in users only and not including already swiped-out users.

Comment: @DaleK Thank you. I have raised a separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66523208/how-do-select-only-swipe-in-users-from-the-table-which-has-all-swipe-records-on

Comment: @SEarle1986 I raised one more question Please help if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66523208/how-do-select-only-swipe-in-users-from-the-table-which-has-all-swipe-records