# How do select only swipe-in users from the table which has all swipe records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server table **task_swipe_rec** which has only 6 columns. I want to know how many people swipe in right now for the assigned task and the list of minutes they spent on those tasks till now.

I am expecting to get the list of tasks that are not swiped out (not completed) and number of minutes spent on each task by the employee who swiped in currently.

| Employee_ID | Task_Id | Swipe_Type | Swipe_In_Out_Time | Department | Emp_Swipe_Rec_PK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EMP1 | TASK1 | I | 2021-03-07 08:00:00.000 | MARKETING | 1 |
| EMP2 | TASK2 | I | 2021-03-07 08:00:00.000 | SALES | 2 |
| EMP1 | TASK1 | O | 2021-03-07 15:00:00.000 | MARKETING | 3 |
| EMP1 | TASK3 | I | 2021-03-07 16:00:00.000 | MARKETING | 4 |

```
SELECT
    one.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    one.TASK_ID
    DATEDIFF( minute, one.SWIPE_IN_OUT_TIME, GETDATE() ) AS TimeSpent,   
FROM
    emp_swipe_rec one
    INNER JOIN emp_swipe_rec two ON two.SWIPE_TYPE = 'I'
WHERE
    one.Employee_Id = two.Employee_Id
    AND
    one.TASK_ID = two.TASK_ID
```

Expected Result :

| Employee_ID | Task_Id | TimeSpent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EMP2 | TASK2 | 130 |
| EMP1 | TASK3 | 40 |

Comment: So whats not working about your query? What are you expected results from the provided data? And does it cover all use cases?

Comment: My query fetches the records of transaction_type='I' from swiped out records too. I want only the records which is not swiped out and employee working on.

Comment: Whats does `GETDATE()` give you right now?

Comment: You should move `one.Employee_Id = two.Employee_Id AND one.TASK_ID = two.TASK_ID` to the `JOIN` criteria.

Comment: @DaleK GetDate() is current datetime stamp to subtract with the swipein timestamp.

Comment: @user15350142 I know what it is, but I am in a different timezone to you, so am getting different results - hence I need to know the **actual** value you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want logic like the following, where you check whether there exists a closing record for every opening record. However it doesn't seem possible to get your expected results using the data provided.

```
DECLARE @emp_swipe_rec table (EMPLOYEE_ID int, TASK_ID int, SWIPE_TYPE char(1), SWIPE_IN_OUT_TIME datetime2);

DECLARE @Now datetime2 = '2021-03-07 16:40:00.000'; --sysdatetime();

INSERT INTO @emp_swipe_rec (EMPLOYEE_ID, TASK_ID, SWIPE_TYPE, SWIPE_IN_OUT_TIME)
VALUES
(1,1,'I','2021-03-07 08:00:00.000'),
(2,2,'I','2021-03-07 08:00:00.000'),
(1,1,'O','2021-03-07 15:00:00.000'),
(1,3,'I','2021-03-07 16:00:00.000');

SELECT I.EMPLOYEE_ID, I.TASK_ID
  , DATEDIFF(MINUTE, I.SWIPE_IN_OUT_TIME, @Now) AS TimeSpent
FROM @emp_swipe_rec I
WHERE SWIPE_TYPE = 'I'
-- Rule out any where a closing record in the future exists
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM @emp_swipe_rec O
  WHERE O.EMPLOYEE_ID = I.EMPLOYEE_ID
  AND O.TASK_ID = I.TASK_ID
  AND SWIPE_TYPE = 'O'
  AND O.SWIPE_IN_OUT_TIME > I.SWIPE_IN_OUT_TIME
);
```

Returns the following using a timestamp which gives 40mins - but unsure how you came up with 130min:

| EMPLOYEE_ID | TASK_ID | TimeSpent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 520 |
| 1 | 3 | 40 |

Please note for future reference, if you provide you sample data this way (DDL+DML) you not only make your question clearer, you also make it much easier for people to answer

Comment: It worked like charm. Thanks a lot for your time and help. Really appreciated !

Comment: How do i remove the hardcoded value and use it with the current time? DECLARE @Now datetime2 = '2021-03-07 16:40:00.000';

Comment: Exactly as you say, remove the hardcoded value and put `getdate()` there instead.